# how to make SnackBar not disappearing or hide after x seconds?

Tags: flutter

i want to make my `SnackBar` waiting for my actions, this is my current code:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'Dissmiss',
                    textColor: Colors.yellow,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                    },
                  ),
                  content: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

in this code i have 'Dissmiss' action, when pressed it will hide my `SnackBar`. If im waiting `SnackBar` is hiding automaticly. How i can make him wait or at least wait specific time?

Answer (score 4):

add a duraton of 1 day

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          action: SnackBarAction(
            label: 'Dissmiss',
            textColor: Colors.yellow,
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
            },
          ),
          content: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              ),
          duration: Duration(days: 1),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the `duration:` property:

```
SnackBar(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 5), //or 'days: 1' the snackBar to stay practically forever
  //...
),
```

The default duration of the `SnackBar` is 4 seconds and in here we override that with 5 seconds.
You can simply look these properties up in the Flutter documentation: [SnackBar class - material library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Snackbar can't wait for fo action and it is not designed to act like that as for [material snackbar doc](https://material.io/components/snackbars).
The behaviour you are looking for is easily achievable with [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/flash).

```
showFlash(
  persistent: true,
  ...
  builder: (..) {
    return Flash(..);
  }
)
```